# Do we cook/boil/<something more appropriate> tea? I'm talking about a specific way of preparation whose description is given below

Tags: word-choice

In northern parts of India, tea is prepared by first boiling the water and then adding sugar,milk and dried tea leaves into it, and then the whole mixture is boiled for 5-6 minutes. We can use "prepare" as an answer to my question, but it's too abstract. Moreover, we can't use it in a sentence like - "Don't purchase teabags. I like cooked/boiled/ tea."

Comment: I'd say "I like my tea brewed (in a pot)." There may be some other better ways to say it.

Comment: In western tea preparation, the leaves are *steeped* for 1.5-6 minutes (depending on type). I prefer *loose* tea leaves to teabags. We don't continue to boil the mixed ingredients as is done with chai.

Comment: When I hear "steeped", I think the person has poured boiling water over tea or a tea bag and let it sit. It is no longer over the heat. I think "boiled" tea would be the least ambiguous, although I don't know that I've ever seen tea prepared in this way.

Comment: Yes, I was editing even as you were commenting. :-)

Comment: I think specifying _chai_ instead of _tea_ would do the trick in most cases.

Comment: @TRomano What do we do with soup? Do we stew it? If we do, can we stew tea as well?

Comment: *Stewed* tea is over-steeped.  We *simmer* soup. We let it  simmer.

Comment: The phrasing of the question makes it sound like there are unstated constraints or requirements? E.g. perhaps you are looking for a one word translation or an answer appropriate to a particular context / audience? Just guessing... I imagine more context would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any verb in English referring to preparing tea that would be understood to mean that loose tea leaves were used and not a tea bag. Maybe tea aficionados have specific terms, but if so, most Americans, anyway, would not know them. So if you want to be clear, you have to give a sentence or so and spell it out. Like, "Don't buy teabags -- I prefer my tea made from loose, dried tea leaves."